# how to get table view row and push to viewController from collectionView that's inside a tableViewCell when tapped button inside collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

My hierarchy like this UINavigationController->UITableviewController -> UITableViewCell -> UICollectionView-> UICollectionViewCell

I have a button inside collectionView cell and I set like this:

```
class AccountTypeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var AccountTypeView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgAccountType: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblAccountTypeTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var txtAccountTypeDescription: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnMoreInfo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnOpenNow: UIButton!
weak var delegate: CustomCollectionCellDelegate?
weak var delegate2:AccountTypeViewController?
@IBAction func btnMoreInfoPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("btnMoreInfoPressed eh dipencet")
    delegate?.OpenNows(wasPressedOnCell: self)
}
@IBAction func btnOpenNowPressed(_ sender: RoundButton) {
    print("btnOpenNowPressed eh dipencet")
    let accountRegular = Account(accountType: "signUp.accountTypeRegular".localized(), code: AccountType.regular)
    let signUpViewController = SignUpViewController.fromStoryboard(name: AppStoryboard.Signup.instance)
    let signUpViewModel = SignupViewModel.shared
    signUpViewModel.accountType = accountRegular
    signUpViewController.signupViewModel = signUpViewModel
    delegate2?.navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpViewController, animated: true)
}

class var CustomCell : AccountTypeCollectionViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AccountTypeCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.last
    return cell as! AccountTypeCollectionViewCell
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}}
```

In tableView cell, I set like this :

```
protocol CustomCollectionCellDelegate:class {
func collectionView(collectioncell:AccountTypeCollectionViewCell?, didTappedInTableview TableCell:AccountTypeTableViewCell, collectionRow: Int)
func OpenNows(wasPressedOnCell cell: AccountTypeCollectionViewCell?)}

class AccountTypeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    weak var cellDelegate:CustomCollectionCellDelegate?
    weak var myParent:AccountTypeViewController?
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionAccountTypeView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblAccountTypeTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let cellReuseId = "CollectionViewCell"
    class var customCell : AccountTypeTableViewCell {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AccountTypeTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.last
        return cell as! AccountTypeTableViewCell
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 289, height: 289)
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout

        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "AccountTypeCell", bundle: nil)
        self.collectionView.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseId)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    var collectionViewOffset: CGFloat {
        get {
            return collectionView.contentOffset.x
        }

        set {
            collectionView.contentOffset.x = newValue
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? AccountTypeCollectionViewCell
        self.cellDelegate?.collectionView(collectioncell: cell, didTappedInTableview: self, collectionRow: indexPath.row)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseId, for: indexPath) as? AccountTypeCollectionViewCell
        cell?.updateCellWithImage(name: "videoCallWaiting")
        setRoundedViewWithBorder(view: (cell?.AccountTypeView)!, borderColor: "999999", bgColor: "FFFFFF")
        cell?.txtAccountTypeDescription.isScrollEnabled = true
        return cell!
    }}
```

In AccountTypeViewController (view controller of tableview) I set like this :

```
extension AccountTypeViewController:CustomCollectionCellDelegate {
    func OpenNows(wasPressedOnCell cell: AccountTypeCollectionViewCell?) {
        print("hasil nya eh dipencet")
        let accountRegular = Account(accountType: "signUp.accountTypeRegular".localized(), code: AccountType.regular)
        let signUpViewController = SignUpViewController.fromStoryboard(name: AppStoryboard.Signup.instance)
        let signUpViewModel = SignupViewModel.shared
        signUpViewModel.accountType = accountRegular
        signUpViewController.signupViewModel = signUpViewModel
        navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpViewController, animated: true)
    }

    func collectionView(collectioncell: AccountTypeCollectionViewCell?, didTappedInTableview TableCell: AccountTypeTableViewCell, collectionRow: Int) {
        print("collectionRow clicked:\(collectionRow)")
    }
}
```

I tried with `delegate2?.navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpViewController, animated: true)`, it cannot push to signUpViewController.

I also tried with `delegate?.OpenNows(wasPressedOnCell: self)` also cannot push to signUpViewController.

And I want also get tableView row inside collectionView cell, how to do that?

Please help me to correct my code so it can push to signUpViewController and get tableView row inside collectionView cell.

Comment: You should push the `UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to the `TableViewController`, don't handle them inside the `tableViewCell`, do that way you can easily get the selected row without another delegate, [here](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) is an example

Comment: @Tj3n, the problem is my TableViewController is empty, inside tableview, I called AccountTypeTableViewCell xib, inside AccountTypeTableViewCell I called another xib (AccountTypeCell)

Comment: AccountTypeTableViewCell xib include UITableViewCell -> UICollectionView. AccountTypeCell xib include UICollectionViewCell and its content

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the delegate that push to the next ViewController between all that mass. Follow this steps and try your delegate again, maybe you forgot to set in the nested components....

//ViewControllerExtension with delegate functions

```
extension AccountTypeViewController:CustomCollectionCellDelegate {
    func OpenNows(wasPressedOnCell cell: AccountTypeCollectionViewCell?) {
        print("hasil nya eh dipencet")
        let accountRegular = Account(accountType: "signUp.accountTypeRegular".localized(), code: AccountType.regular)
        let signUpViewController = SignUpViewController.fromStoryboard(name: AppStoryboard.Signup.instance)
        let signUpViewModel = SignupViewModel.shared
        signUpViewModel.accountType = accountRegular
        signUpViewController.signupViewModel = signUpViewModel
        navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpViewController, animated: true)
    }

    func collectionView(collectioncell: AccountTypeCollectionViewCell?, didTappedInTableview TableCell: AccountTypeTableViewCell, collectionRow: Int) {
        print("collectionRow clicked:\(collectionRow)")
    }
}
```

// ViewController which set itself as a delegate in the table cells...

```
class AccountTypeViewController: UIViewController {
     //......
     //multiple code
     //......

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          //when you dequeue your cell insert the delegate
          // Everything I write next is pseudocode so do not simply copy+paste
          let cell = AccountTypeTableViewCell()
          cell.delegate = self
          return cell
     }

}
```

// Table cell which use the delegate set by the ViewController inside the nested CollectionCells

```
class AccountTypeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
     weak var cellDelegate: CustomCollectionCellDelegate?

     //......
     //multiple code
     //......

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
           //when you dequeue your cell insert the delegate
           // Everything I write next is pseudocode so do not simply copy+paste
           let cell = AccountTypeCollectionViewCell()
           cell.delegate = cellDelegate
           return cell
     }
}
```

// CollectionCell that trigger the delegate function nested between components

```
class AccountTypeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     //......
     //Multiple component
     //......
     weak var delegate: CustomCollectionCellDelegate?

     @IBAction func btnMoreInfoPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
         print("btnMoreInfoPressed eh dipencet")
         delegate?.OpenNows(wasPressedOnCell: self)
     }
 }
```

Try this and make your code easier and cleaner to simplify your future adjustment :)
Tell me if it's work

Comment: it did not work because it did not load customCell and  CustomCell  from xib so, the UI become blank.

Comment: Oh! You can simply remove this
class var customCell : AccountTypeTableViewCell {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AccountTypeTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.last
        return cell as! AccountTypeTableViewCell
    }

and use this code in viewDidLoad()

table.register(UINib(nibName: "AccountTypeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseId)

Follow this tutorial to learn how to use reusableCell with Xib or Nib
http://ios-tutorial.com/custom-uitableviewcell-xib-swift-3/

Comment: I put custom cell of tableView cell xib inside tableView cell with this code func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AccountTypeTableViewCell") as? AccountTypeTableViewCell
        if cell == nil {
            cell = AccountTypeTableViewCell.customCell
        }
        cell?.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell!
    }, because I want to show different collectionView each tableView row (like playstore or appstore).

Comment: Mmmmm probably when you nest the collection view inside the table cell, it can't be find and it show anything on display, try to create a new viewcontroller and follow this steps https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/.
After try to repeat it with your code and see if you are missing something :)

Comment: I got the log of "btnMoreInfoPressed eh dipencet", but I did not got log of "hasil nya eh dipencet". it means it did not come to extension AccountTypeViewController:CustomCollectionCellDelegate (delegate?.OpenNows(wasPressedOnCell: self) did not work)

Comment: Probably because the delegate wasn't set correctly, if you debug it, on terminal you can type po delegate to see that it's nil